# How to properly iterate and style

Tags: python

```
numbers = [ [([random.randint(1, 25)]) for col in range(5) ] for row in range(5)]
```

I want to print it out like a table columns and rows:
This is how I want it, but without the [].

```
 ''' [
        [[13], [8], [2], [5], [17]],
        [[18], [9], [10], [16], [23]],
        [[5], [16], [7], [6], [11]],
        [[7], [7], [24], [10], [24]],
        [[1], [4], [17], [22], [13]]
    ] '''
```

I want

```
   '''
        13  8   2    5    17
        18  9   10   16   23
        5   16  7    6    11
        7   7   10   24   10 
        1   4   17   22   13 
    '''
```

Then if the randint returns 10 different numbers if any of these exist in the list above then it should look like this:

```
   '''
        13  8   2    5    17
        [18]  9   10   16   23
        5   16  7    6    11
        7   7   [10]   24   10 
        1   4   17   22   13 
    '''
```

Comment: Not sure of what you want to achieve here, a table like print out?

Comment: why so many nested lists? what's the point?

Comment: Why not do `from numpy import random; numbers = random.randint(1, 25, size=(5, 5, 1))` to get the array?

Comment: @MadPhysicist numpy is a pretty heavy dependency to bring in just to get an array...

Comment: @nrlakin. Agreed. That's why I didn't make my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick way using `itertools`

```
import itertools

numbers = [ [([random.randint(1, 25)]) for col in range(5) ] for row in range(5)]  
for i in numbers:
    print(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(i))
```

prints

```
11 7 20 16 8
2 16 22 18 10
17 3 17 3 5
24 13 16 12 7
25 9 6 5 19
```

If you know that each row has five elements you can do

```
for i in numbers:
    print('{:<2} {:<2} {:<2} {:<2} {:<2}'.format(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(i)))
```

to print

```
11 7  20 16 8
2  16 22 18 10
17 3  17 3  5
24 13 16 12 7
25 9  6  5  19
```

To print rows of any length, we can do

```
for i in numbers:
    print(('{:<3} '*len(i)).format(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(i)))
```

Which has similar output

Comment: This looks like the only answer that does not change the shape of the array and prints the way OP is asking

Answer (score -1):

I guess I misunderstood what you meant by "without the square brackets". If you keep it as a 2D list of single-element lists, it'd look like this. Obviously you can change the separator at the beginning of the "join" statement to whatever you want.

```
>>> numbers = [ [([random.randint(1, 25)]) for col in range(5) ] for row in range(5)]
>>> for row in numbers:
...     print ", ".join([ elem[0] for elem in row ])
7, 14, 14, 6, 2
25, 22, 22, 16, 8
13, 11, 3, 2, 21
24, 17, 22, 16, 18
7, 6, 20, 4, 20
```

Comment: That's not how I want to print things out.

Comment: One row at a time, without the [] stuff, like this 7  14  14  6  2

Comment: Edited to remove square brackets.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the `numpy` package there's an easier way to generate the numbers:

```
numbers = numpy.random.randint(1, 26, size=[5,5])
```

Note the exclusive upper limit 26, equivalent to setting the inclusive upper limit to 25 in `random.randint`. Note also that this generates a 5x5 array whereas, taken literally, your definition created a 5x5x1 array. If you genuinely intended those innermost brackets in the definition of `numbers`, pass `size=[5,5,1]` instead of `[5,5]`.

Whether you use `numpy` or not, here's a way of printing the 5x5 version:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join('%3d' % number for number in row) for row in numbers))
```

and here is a way of printing the 5x5x1 version:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join('%3d' % seq[0] for seq in row) for row in numbers))
```

Either way, here is a sample output:

```
 21   3  15  19  25
  5  12  13   7  16
 21  24   7   5   1
 11   6  18   1  19
 18   7  20  14   8
```

Comment: Size is actually `5, 5, 1`, also, no brackets in printout.

Comment: Am not convinced the OP necessarily *wanted* `numbers` defined that way, but anyway: edited

Comment: Second comment to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41127912/2988730) answer. Unfortunately OP's actual question is spread among the comments that way.